# Query relating to multiple Dates

Tags: sql, date, grouping

I'm still starting to put my feet into SQL. I have a problem with querying dates and group them. I want to group the dates. And from this dates display the name, type of visit on a specific range of dates.

Say from the example below, I want to query the people who visited from the the range of **01/01/2012 until 31/12/2012** and with type of visit of **4**

[image: Sample table is attached]

Comment: did you try `select .... from .... where .... GROUP BY DATE_OF_VISIT`?

Comment: Thanks. This is what im using. Can't get it.

Comment: if none of the answer works, we need more information, like actual query and table structure

Comment: I'm sorry about this. The thing is how do you get that the first visit falls on your date range only. because several people has multiple visits and their visits falls also on your date range. I want only the people whose first visit is within the range. I don't if that make sence. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM YOUR_tABLE 
WHERE (TYPE_OF_VISIT = 4) AND (DATE_OF_VISIT BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

if you want the first visit of each customer within this range, then you should try sth like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME, T1.DATE_OF_VISIT 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE (T1.TYPE_OF_VISIT = 4) AND (T1.DATE_OF_VISIT BETWEEN ? AND ?)
AND T1.DATE_OF_VISIT = 
(SELECT MIN (T2.DATE_OF_VISIT) FROM YOUR_TABLE T2 WHERE T1.NAME=T2.NAME AND 
(T2.DATE_OF_VISIT BETWEEN ? AND ?))
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I think I'm confusing myself now. Bearing in mind that some names has multiple visit dates and some once visit date only. I will query only the names with one visit only on a specific date range. This will exclude now the names with multiple visits even they are within the range.

Comment: don't forget to click on the up arrow if my answer helped you. thnx!

Comment: thanks. but i still have prolem with this. Is is true that when you group dates you can get earliest and latest dates, say from my example you can validate the first and and last visit?

Comment: check my updated answer. i think this is what you want based on your comments that i read

Comment: Thanks Apostolos. Does this mean that I have two tables? I only have 1 table.

Comment: Thanks Apostolos, This works. Finally got it working, You are the man. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select Name, Type_of_visit
from Appointment_table
where Date_of_visit between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
and Type_of_visit = 4;
```

If you wanted to group the results (and aggregate visits):

```
select Name, Type_of_visit, COUNT(Type_of_visit) as Total_visits
from Appointment_table
where Date_of_visit between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
and Type_of_visit = 4
group by Name, Type_of_visit;
```

Grouping by date will give you a row per unique date, which from your example output didn't look like what you wanted.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Is there a way also of  getting the latest visit of the people thinking that they have multiple visits?

Comment: I'm sorry if my example confused you. It's quite difficult to explain really if you don't really know the SQL yet. After doing the group by, how will i display the earliest of latest dates then. Sorry to be of a pain.

Comment: If you look at my second example with the grouping, you can add the earliest or latest date to the output by putting MIN(Date_of_visit) or MAX(Date_of_visit) into the select. If you want to see all dates, then group by Date_of_visit too (and maybe order), but remember this will group visits on the same day by the same person into one row.

Comment: Thanks once again. Still having problem with this. I still can't display the people only having their first visit between dates. Because some people visited several times and some of their visit is within the range. Their names are being displayed as well. I want only the people whose first visit is within the date range i provide. thanks in advance and I admire your patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

If column Date_of_visit does not contain any time portion (ie. only date). You can execute the following

```
SELECT NAME, TYPE_OF_VISIT
FROM appointment 
WHERE Type_of_visit = 4 
AND Date_of_visit >= '01/01/2012 ' 
AND Date_of_visit <= '31/12/2012'
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But how do i display the name I wanted only. Say this names has multiple visits from different dates and some has one visit only. If I will use this           "SELECT NAME, TYPE_OF_VISIT
FROM appointment 
WHERE Type_of_visit = 4 
AND Date_of_visit >= '01/01/2012 ' 
AND Date_of_visit <= '31/12/2012'
GROUP BY NAME" It would include all the visits that satisfies the date range. What if I wanted to display only the first visit between dates. If that makes sense. Sorry if it not.